How can I sync my local Synology calendar to Google without exposing the Synology to the internet?
I have a Synology NAS where I use the built-in calendar app to manage my different calendars. This works great and I can sync it to my phone using CalDav with the Android app DAVx5.
Now I'd love to have the calendar on my Alexa app to get an overview in the morning. The app only allows me to sync the calendar from, among others, Google. I can add the Synology calendar on the Google Calendar app but the main problem now is that it doesn't get synced back to Google, i.e. it stays local. This results in Alexa calendar not having my Synology events.
Now my question is: Is there any way to get my local calendar to the Google cloud without having to expose my Synology stuff to the internet?
